# News topic detection and categorization

Tags: machine-learning, python, unsupervised-learning, topic-model, lda

If I want to get how many and what kind of topics are covered by New York Times each week from a bag of words model(All the news covered by NYT in a week) how should I approach? Using traditional unsupervised LDA didn't help much.

Comment: You may want to check out [Giveme5W1H](https://github.com/fhamborg/Giveme5W1H), which is an event extractor for news articles, extracting the 5W and 1H journalistic questions, i.e., who did what, when, where, why, and how?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert in this field but you should take a look at the work of Bhargav Srinivasa Desikan, a [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) contributor, who works a lot with topic modelling.

He has a couple of notebooks on his [github account](https://github.com/bhargavvader) which could interest you, especially [this one](https://github.com/bhargavvader/personal/tree/master/notebooks/text_analysis_tutorial) (should be pretty much your use case if I understand your problem correctly).

The aforementioned notebook evaluates Latent Semantic Indexing, the Hierarchical Dirichlet Process as well as the Latent Dirichlet Allocation for identifying topics.